# audio not coming through on share screen using peerjs

Tags: webrtc, peerjs

I'm working on videochat application.
I faced issue like when i share screen & play video from youtube or other sources at time on other side audio is not coming.
Please check my share screen function below.
Any one have idea about this issue?

website link: https://activeknocker.codonnier.tech/webinar/

```
sharescreen.addEventListener('click', () => {
        if (screenStream != null) {
            alert("You Screen Share alredy running.");
            return;
        }
        navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia({
            video: {
                cursor: "always"
            },
            audio: {
                echoCancellation: true,
                noiseSuppression: true
            }
        }).then((stream) => {
            screenStream = stream;
            socket.emit('share', myPeer.id, ROOM_ID);

            let videoTrack = screenStream.getVideoTracks()[0];
            let audiotrack = screenStream.getAudioTracks()[0];
            let micaudiotrack = myVideoStream.getAudioTracks()[0];

            videoTrack.onended = () => {
                stopSharingScreen(videoTrack);
            }

            console.log("stream here", videoTrack);
            pc.forEach(element => {
                let sender = element.peerConnection.getSenders().find(s => s.track && s.track.kind === videoTrack.kind);
                sender.replaceTrack(videoTrack);
            });

            screenStream.getVideoTracks()[0].addEventListener('ended', () => {
                stopSharingScreen(videoTrack);
            });
            broadcastNewTracks(stream, 'video', false);
        }).catch(function(err) {
            console.log(err.name + ": " + err.message);
        });
    });
```